# BackboneJS - Router Functions - Calling Views?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm having an issue calling my views from with the router cfunctions besides within initialize.

this is my router code:

```
var ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
                "": "home",
               //"*actions": "home",
                "photo-gallery": "gallery",
                "sound-lounge": "sound",
                "contact": "contact"
        },
        initialize: function() {
               this.homeView = new window.app.HomeView();
               this.homeView.render();

               /*
               var soundView = new window.app.SoundView();
                soundView.render();

                var contactView = new window.app.ContactView();
                contactView.render();

                var galleryCollection = new window.app.GalleryCollection();
        var gallery_items = galleryCollection.fetch();
         gallery_items.done(function(){
           var gallery_item = new GalleryView({ collection: galleryCollection });
         });
         */



        },
        home: function() {

                console.log('home');
        },
        sound: function() {
               //var soundView = new window.app.SoundView();
                //soundView.render();
                console.log('sound');
        },
         contact: function() {
               //var contactView = new window.app.ContactView();
               // contactView.render();
                console.log('contact');
        },
        gallery: function() {

            console.log('gallery');

        }
});
```

You can see able I have:

```
var soundView = new window.app.SoundView();
soundView.render();
```

commented out within the initalize function, this will work but as soon as I put it within the 'sound' function I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

It's to do with this part: new window.app.SoundView();

I have it called window.app.SoundView in my code, how do I go about getting this to work (it happens incorrectly for all my sections)

// ADDED soundView Code

```
    // SOUNDVIEW    
window.app.SoundView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("html"),
    events: {
      "click #sound-lounge": "render_sound"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.render_sound();
    },
    render: function(model){
        return this;
    },
    render_sound: function(){
        this.model=new window.app.Home({id: 2});
        var $main=this.$el.find('#content-area');
        this.model.fetch().complete(function(data){
            $main.html(data["responseJSON"].description);
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: inside router's initialize try use navigate, and inside sound view call render_sound after render.

Comment: Thanks, I've only just started with backboneJS so I'm not 100% sure what you mean. Any chance there is some sample code that could guide me? Thankyou

Comment: The tutorial by Thomas Davis is really great for getting started with Backbone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk.  See also: http://backbonetutorials.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem ended up being as simple as removing window.app. from the soundView variable name.

e.g.

window.app.SoundView = Backbone.View.extend({ == SoundView = Backbone.View.extend({

AND

var soundView = new window.app.SoundView(); == var soundView = new SoundView();